# Non-static nested class in java

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, static

I expect the output of the below program to be:

```
Inside Static Block A
Inside A
Inside Constructor B
```

But the output is:

```
Inside Static Block A
Inside A
Inside A
Inside A
.
.
.
Inside A(Infinite times)
```

The code is:

```
public class First
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A op=new A();
    }
}
class A
{
    private int a=100;
    private int b;
    A()
    {
        System.out.print("Inside A");
        B obj=new B();
    }
    static
    {
        System.out.print("Inside Static Block A");
    }
    class B
    {
        B()
        {
            System.out.print("Inside Constructor B");
        }
        A o=new A();
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell me why the output is so?

Comment: `B obj=new B();` and `A o=new A();` - what do you think this does?

Answer (score 3):

You have a circular reference between B and A. In the constructor of A you create a B and in B you create a field with an A.

In the constructor of A() you do:

```
B obj = new B();
```

so, you create a new B().

In B() you create a field with an A(). This creates another instance of A() which again creates a B() in its constructor, and so forth.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I have called the constructor A after constructor B block,then how it is able to call it ...

Comment: No @Kai Sternad, I have called the constructor A from outside the constructor B block

Comment: @Raj assigning a value to a field when you declare it is effectively like code which is prepended to the constructor. You are still invoking it whenever you create the instance of B.

Comment: @Kai Sternad,I am a little bit confused,the call to constructor A is outside the block of constructor B,when the call from A to constructor B is made,then the control should come to constructor B and after executing the print statement,it should have returned.

Comment: @RajMalhotra the constructor of B doesn't just return because the fields are also initialized. And that's where the problem is.

Comment: @Raj field assignments happen before the constructor is called, in order that you could potentially use the field values in the ctor.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

```
A() {
    System.out.print("Inside A");
    B obj = new B();
}
```

So to create instance of class `A` you need to create instance of class `B`.

But code of class `B` is

```
class B {
    B() {
        System.out.print("Inside Constructor B");
    }

    A o = new A();
}
```

which (since initialization of fields happens at start of each constructors) is similar to as

```
class B {
    B() {
        o = new A();
        System.out.print("Inside Constructor B");
    }

    A o = null;
}
```

so as you see it also needs to create instance of class `A`.

So when you call

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    A op=new A();
}
```

`new A()` first loads `A` class which executes

```
static {
    System.out.print("Inside Static Block A");
}
```

and then tries to execute constructor `A(){`

```
System.out.print("Inside A");
B obj = new B();
```

but before it ends its execution it calls `new B()` which calls code from constructor `B(){` which as already shown is

```
o = new A();
System.out.print("Inside Constructor B");
```

and we and up with having to create another instance of `A` even before we are able to print `Inside Constructor B`.

So as you see to create instance of class `A` you need to create instance of class `B` which needs to create another instance of class `A` which needs to create another instance of class `B` ... and so on until stack will overflow.

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the fact that you have a circular reference between Class A and Class B.
In your constructor of A you, create an object B

```
 A()
 {
   System.out.print("Inside A");
    B obj=new B(); // You are creating a new object of Class B
 }
```

In Class B you are creating a new object of class A

```
 class B
 {
     B()
     {
        System.out.print("Inside Constructor B");
     }
     A o=new A(); 
 }
```

Here you create an object of class A which again calls the constructor of Class A which creates an object of Class B again and hence the whole process goes into an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

The point is not accessible due recursive calls.

```
B()
{
    System.out.println("Inside Constructor B");
    A o=new A();
}
```

`A o=new A();`

This code should return desired output:

```
Inside Static Block A
Inside A
Inside Constructor B
```